# Get ID from HTML form - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a html form for get Id from visitor

```
<form action="show.php" method="post">
 <p>Your id: <input type="text" name="id" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

and the php file for act this .

```
<?php
$id = ((int)$_GET["id"]);
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
mysql_select_db('dbname',$con);
$query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = '$id'";
$select=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
echo $row['name'];
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

but it's not working , can't read id , pelase help me for resolve this issue

Thank you

Comment: Use  **$_POST** or **$_REQUEST** to collect the form data sent using post method

Comment: @CodingHorror: using $_REQUEST is never a good practice because it creates unnecessary security holes when you are not carefully enough just once. You always better use explicit $_POST or $_GET for exactly that data source you are expecting to be submitted data from

Comment: thank you about complete information , the problem has been solved. that was my crazy mistake :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have used form method "post", id variable will be available in the global $_POST array so use:

```
<?php
$id = ((int)$_POST["id"]);
....
```

Answer (score 8):

You are submitting data via POST.
Thats defined by the attribute "method" within your form tag:

```
<form action="show.php" method="post">
```

So data will not be stored in $_GET but in $_POST.

So to access the ID use $_POST['id'] not $_GET['id']

Answer (score 3):

Use POST intead of Get because use set post method for form.

```
$id = ((int)$_POST["id"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your form is submitting data via POST so you have to accept it via POST method

```
<?php
   $id = $_POST['id'];
?>
```

otherwise change the method to GET and write it like this

```
$id = ((int)$_GET["id"]);
```