# Error when trying to get the button id using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am generating a list of buttons with the id being a value extracted from a database. Then I want to take this id and display. But, when I try to do that, I get an error. Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Button generation

```
 //This function will display items  
 function showItems($sqlString)
 {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connectToDb(), $sqlString);
    //var_dump($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {           
        foreach ($result as $row) 
        {                 
            echo "<div class='div_item'>";
            echo  "<img src='../images/uploads/".$row['It_image']."' style='width:200px;height:150px;'>"."<br>";
            echo  "IT CODE: ".$row['It_code']."<br>"; 
            echo  "ITEM: ".$row['It_name']."<br>"; 
            echo  "DESC: ".$row['It_desc']."<br>"; 
            echo  "QTY AVAIL: ".$row['qty']."<br>"; 
            echo  "PRICE: ".$row['price']."<br>";
                echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST'>";
                echo  "<button type='submit' name='id' id='".$row['It_code']."'>Buy</button>";
                echo  "</form>";
            echo  "</div>";
        }
   }
}
```

Displaying the ID when the respective button is clicked

```
  //get id of the button
  if (isset($_POST['id']))
  {
    echo $_GET['id'];
  }
```

Error

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558523/get-id-from-html-form-php#:~:text=php%20%24id%20%3D%20((int),mysql_close(%24con)%3B%20%3F%3E check it maybe it will help you

Comment: When POST used I don't get any output

Comment: You have used form method "post", id variable will be available in the global $_POST array also inspect your page and check id first .

Comment: "POST" method is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it inside value  value='".$row['It_code']."'

```
 echo  "<button type='submit' value='".$row['It_code']."' name='id' id='".$row['It_code']."'>Buy</button>";
```

Comment: Thanks. As you said it has to be passed as a value in order to get it from POST. I also used a hidden field and it solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `var_dump($result)`, the error message tells us it can't find the key "id". So var_dump could give us more information about what is missing.

It could be because the form method is post, that data will be stored in the `$_POST['id']` and not `$_GET['id']`